# using loop to insert 100000 data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to insert data(100000) with a loop in mysql.
When i run no error,but data not insert into my table.

this my query :

```
DELIMITER //
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE i <= 100 DO
  INSERT INTO vouchers VALUES (i,'val1','val2','val3');
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
DELIMITER ;
```

structur table :

```
id int(11)[autoincrement]
data1 varchar(100)
data2 varchar(100)
data3 varchar(100)
```

how to fix my query ?
thanks..

Comment: Don't provide a value for auto increment field, if its a must, send 0 and it will be ignored

Comment: Doesn't MySQL have some ID column that you can set as a primary key and have it auto-increment on each `INSERT`? This eliminates (probably) the need for `i`.

Comment: Your code should fail with an error, unless it is inside a stored procedure, function, or trigger.  That is where control flow syntax is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert your 100000 rows without a procedure with this unwieldy statement:

```
INSERT INTO
    vouchers
SELECT
    t.n, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + d.N * 1000 + e.N * 10000 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) e
    ORDER BY n
) t;
```

To use the autoincrement feature replace the t.n by NULL:

```
INSERT INTO
    vouchers
SELECT
    NULL, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + d.N * 1000 + e.N * 10000 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) e
    ORDER BY n
) t;
```

Comment: That's long-winded and time consuming for the OP- perhaps post a different method?

Comment: It's not time consuming if compared to row by row inserting. A procedure that inserts these rows in a loop as the original code will be very slow compared to this.