# MYSQL: Update all values in existing column

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
>     +-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+
>     | score | likes | views | orders | image_ratings | part_number |
>     +-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+
>     |     0 |     2 |     0 |      0 |             0 | 1030-507629 |
>     |     0 |     1 |     0 |      0 |             0 | 1070-B265A  |
>     |     0 |     2 |     0 |      0 |             0 | 1070-B26UY  |
>     +-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

I want to update all the scores with the values 1,2,3 (respectively) so it will look like this:

```
>     +-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+
>     | score | likes | views | orders | image_ratings | part_number |
>     +-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+
>     |     1 |     2 |     0 |      0 |             0 | 1030-507629 |
>     |     2 |     1 |     0 |      0 |             0 | 1070-B265A  |
>     |     3 |     2 |     0 |      0 |             0 | 1070-B26UY  |
>     +-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

I want to perform this update in one statement but don't know how. Im thinking

```
UPDATE table1 SET score = (1,2,3);
```

However this doesn't work.

Comment: To update a table use an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT`.

Comment: Is there any sorting for? So what line should become 1, what line maybe 15110

Comment: no sorting. the values i put in are already pre sorted.

Comment: How does SQL will know in which line it will put 1, or 2, or 3? The assumption the SQL will return lines always in the same order is not true.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with this compound query:

```
SET @a := 0;    
UPDATE example2 e3 INNER JOIN (
    -- part to generate the numbers from 1 to 3
    -- could easily adapted to your needs
    SELECT N, e2.A, e2.part_number FROM (
        SELECT 1 as N UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    ) as n
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            @a := @a + 1 as A,
            e.*
        FROM
            example2 e
    ) as e2
    ON
        n.N = e2.A
) t
ON 
    e3.part_number = t.part_number
SET
    e3.score = t.A;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b1c8/1)

If you need some numbers more, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164199/using-loop-to-insert-100000-data-in-mysql/25164401#25164401)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is what you're intending on doing, but if you're looking to add a set of incrementing value to the score column, you can do that with the following statements:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN `temp` int key auto_increment;
UPDATE table1 SET score = temp;
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN temp;
```

If you are just trying to update one column for multiple rows not based on other column values but instead with values from your application, you'll need to create multiple queries. MYSQL needs to know which columns to affect, and it cannot rely just on the order they are stored in the table without any other value.

If you are trying to do this in one query to maintain consistency with your data, I suggest using a 'START TRANSACTION;' before your set of updates, checking that each succeeded, then running 'COMMIT;' at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SET @i = 0;  
 UPDATE table1 SET score = @i:=@i+1;
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are (sometimes) good, but code+explanation answers are (almost always) better

Comment: This code isn't very difficult to understand, just a variable incrementation, i can add link to the doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html